# Using Docker and Virtualbox together on an Ubuntu Host?

Tags: linux, virtualbox, virtual-machine, docker, hypervisor

So I set up Docker on a Ubuntu 16.04 Host and then installed Virtualbox on the same host to have some Virtual Machines. but after working for a while, I found out that I can only install 32-bit OS on a VM. I looked and made sure that my host supports 64-bit and has VT-X enabled. 
The only thing comes to my mind is that Docker using VT-X so I cant use a hypervisor to install 64-bit Operating Systems.
As far as I found out, having VT-X on a Linux host to run Docker is not must but seems like having it helps to provide a better performance. 
So this leads to my question:
Is there a way to prevent Docker from using VT-X even if it was enabled and unused on a host? Maybe installing the hypervisor (in this case VirtualBox) could help but I'm not sure.
Appreciations in Advance!

Comment: Is the main Ubuntu (the "outer shell") 64-bit? And the next "shell" is Docker, and the next "shell" is VirtualBox that will only install 32-bit? Searched for how to install 64-bit in VirtualBox?

Comment: @Xen2050 Thats right. I just did that but doesn't help in any way. I can select  a  64bit OS iso but the setup don't go through

Comment: There was a VirtualBox setting about 64-32 bit os's but I'm sure you already found & tried it (and I don't remember it offhand anyway). I'd guess it's the Docker then... If you run VirtualBox directly in Ubuntu (with no Docker in between) does it work ok then?